# How to set a style for a particular cell in a multiindex dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I'm iterating over a multi-index dataframe, and I trying to set the color for particular cells to the style in the two variables `points_color` and `stat_color`.

***How to apply the style to the cells?***

```
for metric, new_df in df3.groupby(level=0):
    idx = pd.IndexSlice
    row = new_df.loc[(metric),:]
    for geo in ['US', 'UK']:
        points_color, stat_color = color(new_df.loc[metric,idx[:,:,['difference']]][geo]['']['difference'],
                                   new_df.loc[metric,idx[:,:,['stat']]][geo]['']['stat'])
        

#####  SEE HERE  #######
        df3.loc[metric,idx[:,:,['points']]][geo]['GM']['points'] = # apply points_color style to this value df3.loc[metric,idx[:,:,['points']]][geo]['GM']['points']
        df3.loc[metric,idx[:,:,['stat']]][geo]['']['stat'] = # apply stat_color style to this value df3.loc[metric,idx[:,:,['stat']]][geo]['']['stat']
###########

df3
```

---

**Setup for the dataframe:**

```
dic = {'US':{'Quality':{'points':"-2 n", 'difference':'equal', 'stat': 'same'}, 'Prices':{'points':"-7 n", 'difference':'negative', 'stat': 'below'}, 'Satisfaction':{'points':"3 n", 'difference':'positive', 'stat': 'below'}},
      'UK': {'Quality':{'points':"3 n", 'difference':'equal', 'stat': 'above'}, 'Prices':{'points':"-13 n", 'difference':'negative', 'stat': 'below'}, 'Satisfaction':{'points':"2 n", 'difference':'negative', 'stat': 'same'}}}
d1 = defaultdict(dict)
for k, v in dic.items():
    for k1, v1 in v.items():
        for k2, v2 in v1.items():
            d1[(k, k2)].update({k1: v2})

df = pd.DataFrame(d1)

df.columns = df.columns.rename("Skateboard", level=0)
df.columns = df.columns.rename("Metric", level=1)

df3 = pd.concat([df], keys=[''], names=['Q3'], axis=1).swaplevel(0, 1, axis=1)
df3.columns = df3.columns.map(lambda x: (x[0], 'GM', x[2]) if x[2] == 'points' else x)
df3.insert(loc=0, column=('','', 'Mode'), value="Website")

df3
```

**Setup for the color function:** It takes two cell values difference and stat and determines if the style for cells points and stats is in the dataframe.

```
def color(difference, stat):
    points_color, stat_color = '', ''
    
    if stat in ('below', 'above'):
        stat_color = 'background-color: #f2dcdb; color: red'
    
    if difference == "negative":
        points_color = 'color: red'
    elif difference == "positive":
        points_color = 'color: green' 
    
    return points_color, stat_color
```

Comment: What columns should be colored?

Comment: @jezrael So, 1. the column stat gets both the color and the background color if the value in the stat column is below or above. 2. The value in the points column gets colored green or red if the value in the difference column is positive or negative.

Comment: So `points` colors are colored by `difference` masks and `stat` columns are colored by `stat` mask?

Comment: I find typoin my answer, need `.rename(columns={'difference':'points'}`

Comment: Also, how to export the dataframe to excel without losing the style?

Comment: If export to excel [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/style.html#Export-to-Excel) not working?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249969/discussion-between-m-j-and-jezrael).

Comment: Some problem with write to excel?

Comment: I'm getting the excel file with formatting. I had another question: How can I set the background color of the entire level of headers (needed only for 1 and 2) to black and the font color to white? I'm trying the following:

```def highlight_x(s):
return ["background-color: black; color: white"]

df3.style.apply_index(highlight_x, axis="columns", level=[1, 2])```

Comment: Can you try only `def highlight_x(s): return "background-color: black; color: white"` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select `geo` columns by list, compare `stat` and `difference` and set values in slices:

```
def color(x):
    
    idx = pd.IndexSlice
    geo = ['US', 'UK']
    
    m1 = x.loc[:, idx[geo, :, 'stat']].isin(('below', 'above'))
    diff = x.loc[:, idx[geo, :, 'difference']]
    
    df1 = pd.DataFrame('', index=x.index, columns=x.columns)
    
    diff = (diff.rename(columns={'difference':'points'}, level=2)
                 .rename(columns={'':'GM'}, level=1))
    df1.loc[:, idx[geo, 'GM', 'points']] = np.select([diff.eq('negative'), 
                                                      diff.eq('positive')], 
                                                     ['color: red','color: green'], '')
    df1.loc[:, idx[geo, :, 'stat']] = np.where(m1, 
                                           'background-color: #f2dcdb; color: red', '')
                     
    return df1

df.style.apply(color, axis=None)
```